# Computing time complexity in code - Nested loops

Tags: python, loops, nested

I am trying to run this code on an excel sheet which has three sheets. 
Sheet 1 - contains 18000 rows
Sheet 2 - contains 6500 rows
Sheet 3 - contains 2500 rows

I want to mask the sensitive information by comparing the key words in my master file. However, this code is taking forever to run on only one function -

```
wb= openpyxl.load_workbook("NewContent.xlsx")

from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

length = len(wb.sheetnames)

def comp():
    for num in range(0, length, 1):
        wb.active = num
        sheet = wb.active

        max_row=sheet.max_row
        max_column=sheet.max_column

        cmp = pd.read_excel('Client_names.xlsx', sheet_name=0)
        mylist = cmp['ClientName'].tolist()

        for i in range(2,max_row+1):
             for j in range(1,max_column+1):
                  cell_obj=sheet.cell(row=i,column=j)
                  for k in range(0, len(mylist), 1):
                     if fuzz.token_sort_ratio(cell_obj.value, mylist[k]) > 80:
                         cell_obj.value = 'Company'
                         wb.save('NewContent_Masked.xlsx')
                         break


comp()
```

Any alternatives for optimising the code

Comment: For starter, may I know why you are reading Excel file in loop?

Comment: Im confused, why are you using two different methods to read the two excel sheets? Just stick with `pd`. However, bottom line, even without looking at the rest of the code, I think you don't recognize how *slow* it is to interface between excel and python cell by cell. You need to get the whole data in memory at once, multiple calls like `cell_obj=sheet.cell(row=i,column=j)` Essentially give you the worst performance.

Comment: I am essentially new to python and probably dont know the best way to optimise the code.

Comment: Get the entire data in memory first, for example in dataframes. you're already using `pd` for one of them, use `pd` for all the data first. and then proceed further. Explore how to read multiple sheets if that is your hurdle.